# Phantom null pointer exception when listing files in directory in Android app

Tags: java, android, io

First off, many thanks for taking a moment to look at my question. I'll try to keep it brief but clear.

My end goal for this activity (the main activity for my app) is to read all files in a folder and list them in a spinner so the user can select which to load. Right now I'm running into a null pointer exception somewhere in my for loop where I get the filenames from a File[] list.

Here's the class code. As you can see I haven't actually gotten to the spinner yet.

```
    package ca.sulli.quilxotic;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Launcher extends Activity {

    public static Reader reader;
    public static Book book;

    /* FILE IO */
    public static File sdCard;
    public static File directory;
    public static File[] fileList;
    public static ArrayList<String> fileNameList;

    /* INTERFACE */
    public Spinner bookSpinner;
    public CheckBox debugCheck;
    public Button beginBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* CUSTOM LAYOUT SETUP */
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Remove title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //Remove notification bar

        setContentView(R.layout.launcher);

        bookSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.bookSpinner);
        debugCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.debugCheck);
        beginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.beginBtn);

        sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Quilxotic");

        if(!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdir();

        Log.e(null,"Copying content to SDCard");
        CopyContent();
        Log.e(null,"Done copying content to SDCard");

        fileList = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath()).listFiles();
        int fileCount = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath()).list().length;
        Log.e(null,fileCount + " files found in /Quilxotic...");

        for (File file : fileList){
            fileNameList.add(file.getPath());
            Log.e(null,"Added file: " + file.getPath());
        }

/*
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fileNameList);

        bookSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        bookSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        }); {

        }

*/
}

    private void OpenBook()
    {
        book = new Book();
        reader = new Reader(book);
    }

    private void CopyContent()
    {

        File f = new File(getCacheDir()+"/example.xml");
        if (!f.exists()) try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("example.xml");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String originPath = "/data/ca.sulli.quilxotic/cache/example.xml";
                String destPath = "Quilxotic/example.xml";
                File currentXML = new File(data, originPath);
                File backupXML = new File(sd, destPath);

                if (currentXML.exists() && !backupXML.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentXML).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupXML).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                } else {
                    Log.e(null, "File does not exist: " + currentXML.toString() + "or destination XML exists");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(null, "SDCard not writable, backup aborted.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(null, "Error backing up database to sdcard.", ex);
        }
    }


}
```

For reasons I can't fathom, I'm hitting a null pointer exception somewhere in that for loop. If I comment out the for loop the app loads the layout correctly. Here's the stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.sulli.quilxotic/ca.sulli.quilxotic.Launcher}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ca.sulli.quilxotic.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:73)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And for completion's sake, here's my manifest. I only have two activities, the launcher where the user chooses which file to load, and the reader that will (eventually) parse the file and act upon it. So far as I can determine there's nothing immediately wrong with my other classes that would cause this, but maybe I've set the manifest up wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.sulli.quilxotic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 

    >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/quill"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ca.sulli.quilxotic.Launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ca.sulli.quilxotic.Reader"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="ca.sulli.quilxotic.Launcher">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks again to anyone who takes a look. I'll keep fiddling with it in the meantime, but I just can't see what's wrong with that for loop or the file list it iterates over. Thanks!

Updated: Trying to bring this in line with guidelines. The question has been resolved, but for the sake of completion:

1. Have you done some research before asking the question?
    I've gone through several examples and stack overflow pages about creating a filelist from a directory.
2. Have you explained what you've already tried to solve your problem?
    As mentioned, commenting out the For loop solves the exception. I've also tried different ways to write the For loop, and ensured that all variables up until that point contain valid data.
3. Have you specified which language and platform you're using, including version number where relevant?
    This is Android with a minAPI of 8. I'm using the Android Studio IDE.
4. If your program produces different results to what you expected, have you stated what you expected, why you expected it, and the actual results?
    It should create me an ArrayList of the filenames of files in a directory as strings. Of course it shouldn't crash as well.
5. Have you read the whole question to yourself carefully, to make sure it makes sense and contains enough information for someone coming to it without any of the context that you already know?
    Yes.

Comment: why don't you debug your code before asking when exception is a simple NullPointerException? any way, as WhoAml said, you have not initialized fileNameList...

Comment: Oh, believe me, I spent hours trying to debug. What's simple to you isn't simple to me. The IDE doesn't point out that this isn't initialised, which it usually does, hence my confusion. The callstack doesn't appear to obviously refer to this variable, so I asked for help. I appreciate the response though.

Comment: I've updated the question using the guidelines and checklist referenced. While my mistake is obvious to others, I feel the question is clear, the information provided adequate, and easily solvable by others. If not, please clarify and I'll revise. This community has been invaluable to my learning so far, and if like to know how to best contribute questions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `fileNameList` before accessing it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Many thanks! Usually the IDE calls out uninitialised variables as errors so I missed that. Your help is much appreciated, thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Worth noting that this didn't work as-written. Instead "new ArrayList<>();" it should be "new ArrayList();" without the diamond brackets.